# What is a good substitute for "can be seen to"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a phrase that can be used instead of "can be seen to" in an analytical context

e.g. "...each of whom can be seen to represent..."

Comment: Needs a full sentence. Why don't you provide the sentence sample? Please explain why "can be seen to" is unsatisfactory. Is this for a paper? Please give a bit more detail so that users can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Can be see to
How about a single word, e.g., reveals, demonstrates, shows, leads to the conclusion, vs. can be seen to reveal, etc. I'm suggesting that "can be seen to" is filler and fuzzy.  Xanne